# In gnome files: how do I remove credentials I told it save permanently to connect to a share under the smb protocol

Tags: gnome, gnome-keyring

If I have incorrect credentials saved, should it prompt me for a username and password?  I'm getting "Connection Refused" and I'm assuming it's the bad credentials I know I put in there.

os is Fedora 39

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the credentials; you're unable to connect to the server to authenticate.